# /etc/hosts configuration not being detected

Tags: linux, apache, virtualhost, hosts, document-root

Am configuring a local linux development environment utilizing apache, i can access the url:

```
http://localhost:8080
```

but not the configured virtualhost entries which are also present in the /etc/hosts file e.g if i enter:

```
http://admin:8080
```

in my browser redirects me to www.admin.com, which is an external address.

/etc/hosts file has the following entries:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost admin jobboard

127.0.1.1   rob-VirtualBox
```

Apache config(virtual hosts reference the above entries admin and jobboard):

```
Listen 8080

Port 8080

ServerName 127.0.0.1:8080

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/BigRedSkyASAP/virtualhosts"

<Directory "/var/www/html/BigRedSkyASAP/virtualhosts">

NameVirtualHost *:8080

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
ServerName admin

# set the document root
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/BigRedSkyASAP/virtualhosts/Client-asap.bigredsky.com"

# set the directory settings
<Directory "/var/www/html/BigRedSkyASAP/virtualhosts/Client-asap.bigredsky.com">
    Options All Includes Indexes
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
ServerName jobboard

# set the document root
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/BigRedSkyASAP/virtualhosts/JobBoard-asapdev.bigredsky.com"

# set the directory settings
<Directory "/var/www/html/BigRedSkyASAP/virtualhosts/JobBoard-asapdev.bigredsky.com">
    Options All Includes Indexes
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Apache and Computer was restarted after changes to config files were saved.
Is their some other hosts configuration file which needs to be modified? Running linux mint OS.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you ping admin ? (The admin to www.admin.com normally happens in the browser if it can't find admin. Also Do you type the http:// in the browser. That normally helps, but it depends on your browser)

Comment: It looks like the first Directory tag is never closed.

Comment: I can ping admin rob@rob-VirtualBox ~ $ sudo ping admin
PING localhost (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.048 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.041 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.044 ms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the virtual host config try this for admin

**ServerAlias admin**

that should resolve the admin website to local server
furthermore check whether you are under any proxy...you should turn it off...

Comment: Thanks Amol configuring proxy correctly worked. Added 'admin' and 'jobboard' under No Proxy settings on browser

Answer (score 0):

create one more vhost entry for admin

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
ServerName admin
```